# На один и тот же GET запрос - сервер присылает разные http-заголовки

Tags: http, https

Подскажите пожалуйста, а какова может быть причина, того, что север отвечает по разному на один и тот же GET-запрос, но с разных IP-шников (и с разных компов).

-На GET-запрос с одного компа и соответвенно IP-адреса - сервер присылает заголовок Location.

-На GET-запрос с другого компа и соответвенно другого IP-адреса- сервер не присылает заголовок Location.

Comment: Значит сервер хочет отвечать по-разному разным IP-адресам. Почему — спрашивайте у администратора сервера

Comment: @ andreymal, спасибо, как то это все загадочно :)